# Bootstrap model AJAX request cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I meet a problem when I build bootstrap HTML.

There is model in html when the button click the model is show and the model load data from ajax request that is post request. When I click button it always load the previous request, like image as follow:
[request error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzYuW.png)

so how can I load the current request via model?
The code is like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit_dialplan" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h4 class="modal-title">
....
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function ShowEditPanel(id) {
            var basht='<div id="legend" class=""><legend class="">list<button id="add_edit_ivrs_rulers" style="position: relative;left: 355px;" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Add rule</button></legend></div>';
            $('#edit_dialplan').on('shown.bs.modal',function() {
                $.post("/api/dialplans/info/?number="+Math.random(), {name: id},function(data) {
                    $("#edit_name").val(data.name);
                    var str="";
                    $.each(jQuery.parseJSON(data.rules), function(k,v){
                        str+='<div class=\"control-group\"><label class=\"control-label\" for=\"edit_rule\"><\/label><input id=\"edit_arg\" name=\"edit_arg\"  class=\"input-mini\" type=\"text\" value='+v+'><span class=\"ruler_up\">↑<\/span><span class=\"ruler_down\">↓<\/span><span class=\"ruler_del\">-<\/span><\/div>';
            });
            $("#edit_rulers").html(basht+str);

                },'json');
            });
        }
```

Comment: Your issue is that you are getting an old cached image?

Comment: Are you saying you want to request the endpoint with the same number on the query string? If so, please store the generated number and add it to the modal's data.

Comment: Are you clicking modal more than once??